# Sometimes getting PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, persistence, derby

There are many questions about this PersistenceException, but I have not seen some, where the specific line of code throws this exception only sometimes (but not randomly:-).

So, do you have any idea, why once my simple app finds the provider ok, but then later it won't?

NetBeans IDE 7.0.1, NetBeans Platform app, using persistence link library and Derby embbed.

I was trying [this CRUD creatable capabilities "tutorial" by Geertjan](http://netbeans.dzone.com/loosely-coupled-creatable-capabilities), but i get the PersistenceException when saving new Trip:

```
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
at org.mv.mm.api.TripSearchDAO.createTransactionalEntityManager(TripSearchDAO.java:61)
at org.mv.mm.api.TripSearchDAO.create(TripSearchDAO.java:41)
at org.mv.mm.api.TripQuery$3.create(TripQuery.java:69)
[catch] at org.mv.mm.api.TripType.create(TripType.java:64)
```

But in "search" method of DAO class, there is this private method createTransactionalEntityManager called too and EntityManager correctly created. Why it might be?

---

Ok, the problem is similar like many others here (well, I have not solved it, but I will try again tomorrow). It fails every time. I have mislooked the try catch block, so I did not noticed the exception. It occurs every time the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TripPU").createEntityManager() is called.

Comment: Something doesn't add up between the exception you posted and the code you linked. The trace shows that the exception is thrown @ line 61 of TripSearchDAO.java, which is an empty formatting line in the code you linked to...

Comment: Yes, of course, my code is a bit different. In reality, it is line 52:
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TripPU").createEntityManager();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the real solution to the real problem is also found: Really do check in those cases the name of your persistence unit in persistence.xml (like TripPU) if it is correct to the calling Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TripPU").createEntityManager();

The PU is not same as the DB entity, so the tutorials might you confuse when you try to do a bit different example (different tables etc.).

Comment: No for me, the topic is closed completely.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this question is answered:
The reason, why the PersistenceException occurs only sometimes, is that the other time, when it seems, everything is OK, the problematic line:

```
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TripPU").createEntityManager();
```

is called from another class from try... catch block, where the "catch" block does nothing. So I have not noticed that it fails always.

Comment: To admins: I don't know, according to the policy of Stackoverflow, it makes me sense that I close my question this way. And maybe create another question (which emerged from this one), or find the solution in already answered similar questions. This one is useful for those, who would do similar tutorial and encounter the problem that this happend only SOMETIMES. So I don't see renaming all the question and rewriting it whole as very useful for them.